# Group string values

Tags: c#, string, stringbuilder

I have this code

```
var myBuilder = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var item in myList)
{
  myBuilder.Append(item.Number).Append(" - ").Append(item.SecondNumber).Append(", ");
}

var text = myBuilder;
```

and using that I'm getting this text

> AAA08 - BB08, AAA09 - BB09, AAA09 - BB10,

***myList*** returns this:

> { Number = "AAA08", SecondNumber = "BB08" }
>
> { Number = "AAA09", SecondNumber = "BB09" }
>
> { Number = "AAA09", SecondNumber = "BB10" }

How can I concatenate it to string to display this:

> AAA08 - BB08; AAA09 - BB09, BB10

I can do replace `,` to `;` but can't get how to group these `Number`to display only one and each `SecondNumber` right to him

Comment: @FirstStep mylist is query which returns list from database. It's complex and has nothing to do with that question. I've provided code which is returned by myList

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with Linq and `string.Join`

```
var grouped = myList
    .GroupBy(x => x.Number)
    .Select(g => g.Key + " - " + string.Join(", ", g.Select(x => x.SecondNumber)))
var text = string.Join("; ", grouped);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GroupBy` and `String.Join`:

```
var groupedNumbers= myList
    .GroupBy(x => x.Number)
    .Select(g => $"{g.Key} - {String.Join(", ", g.Select(x => x.SecondNumber))}");
string result = String.Join("; ", groupedNumbers);
```

I'm using string interpolation which is a C#6 feature, if you aren't using it replace `$"{g.Key}..."` with  `String.Format("{0}...", g.Key, ..)`.

Answer (score 0):

When you get `Number`, iterate through `myList` to find all instances of `Number`, then get each corresponding `SecondNumber` and append it to your string.

Answer (score 0):

Before building final string you probably would need to group your array first with this code:
`var groupedList = myList.GroupBy(x => x.Number)`
and later use that grouped list to get proper string:

```
foreach (var item in groupedList) 
{
    myBuilder.Append(item.Number).Append(" - ").Append(item.Select(x => x.SecondNumber).Join(", ")).Append("; ");
}
```